# How to set iptables mark when sending a packet?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, iptables

Linux's iptable and iproute allows us to mark packets and matches the mark later (fwmark), allowing for great flexibility in configuring routes and firewalls.

Is there a way to set those marks while sending the packet from a C program, either via ordinary sockets interface or via specific linux system calls?

Comment: Manipulating marks is one of those things that should require root privilege.

Comment: @BenVoigt There are many things that require root privileges, and many programs needs to be run as root. What is your point?

Comment: That if your "a C program" doesn't run as root, you may never find a way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the `SO_MARK` socket option in socket(7) man page:

> ```
>    SO_MARK (since Linux 2.6.25)
> ```

```
          Set the mark for each packet sent through this socket (similar
          to the netfilter MARK target but socket-based).  Changing the
          mark can be used for mark-based routing without netfilter or
          for packet filtering.  Setting this option requires the
          CAP_NET_ADMIN capability.
```

It is not per packet, as I originally asked, suits my purpose. You can set it with `setsockopt()`:

```
int fwmark;
//fwmark = <some value>;

if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_MARK, &fwmark, sizeof fwmark) == -1)
    perror("failed setting mark for socket packets");
```